# Deduce expected value from conditional probability

Tags: probability, integration

If you have:

$$\begin{align*}
P(x) & = \mathcal N(x\mid\mu_x, \sigma^2_x) \\
P(y\mid x) & = \mathcal N(y\mid ax+b,\sigma^2_y)
\end{align*}$$

I want to calculate $E(Y)$.
I can see intuitively that it should be equal to $a\mu_x + b$

How do you derive that properly?

This is what I have thought:

$$\begin{align*}
E(Y) & = \int yp(y) \ dy\\
p(y) & = \int p(y\mid x) p(x) \ dx
\end{align*}$$
How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Why are you destroying your question? $E(Y) = \int y \ d P(y)$ is correct...

Comment: Indeed. Both current formulas are absurd.

Comment: @AlexR eh... no comment

Comment: @Spacemonkey [Eh, no comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition)...

Comment: @Did sorry, I didn't notice I swapped them.

Comment: @AlexR yes, I was wrong.

Comment: Leonbloy's got the answer so I won't post one.  I've always thought the kind of notation used in this question is obnoxious.  Using the same letter, $p$, for several different functions makes you wonder what is meant by $p(3)$, the function evaluated at the point where its input is $3$.  If you call the random variable $X$ and distinguish between capital $X$ and lower-case $x$, then you can understand expressions like $\Pr(X\le x)$, and $f_X(3)$ and $f_Y(3)$ are the values of the density functions of two different random variables evaluated at $3$. And $f_{X\mid Y}(x)$ also become unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) (or "tower rule"), which says $E(Y) = E(E(Y\mid X))$

In your case, you know that $E(Y\mid X)= a X +b$. Hence $E(Y)=E(a X+b) = a \mu_x +b$

Answer (score 0):

Two different questions here:

> How do you derive that properly?

For example, by noting that the definition of conditional distribution says exactly that $Y$ is distributed as $aX+b+\sigma_YZ$ where $Z$ is standard normal (and independent of $X$) hence $E(Y)=aE(X)+b+\sigma_Y E(Z)=a\mu_X+b$.

> This is what I have thought: $E(Y)=\displaystyle\int yp(y) dy$ (and) $p(y)=\displaystyle∫p(y|x)p(x) dx.$
>   How do I proceed from here?

For example, by plugging the second identity into the first one, getting
$$E(Y)=\iint yp(y|x)p(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
and inserting the values of $p(x)$ and $p(y|x)$ in the double integral on the RHS. The computations that follow are boring but they carry through. One can (prove and) use as an intermediate step the fact that
$$
\int yp(y|x)\mathrm dy=ax+b.
$$