# Linear Gaussian system, covariance of the normalisation constant

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If we have the following multivariate Gaussian distributions:

$$p(x) = N(x|\mu_x,\Sigma_x)$$

$$p(y|x) = N(y|Ax + b, \Sigma_y)$$

Now how can you deduce **p(y)** ?

p(y) is called *the normalisation constant* for some reason that I haven't figured out, yet.

You can see that $$E(Y) = E(E(Y|X)) = E(Ax + b) = A\mu_x + b$$

Now, how about the covariance of y, how would you calculate that?

This paper actually explains it (proof of fact 2):
http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/C.Bracegirdle/bayesTheoremForGaussians.pdf

But I cannot figure out why the following is true:

$$y = Mx+\epsilon, \epsilon \sim \mathcal N(y\mid b,\Sigma_y)  $$

Why is y equal to that?

EDIT: This quotes answers to this question about calculating the expectation:
[Deduce expected value from conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660887/deduce-expected-value-from-conditional-probability)

Comment: Please mention http://math.stackexchange.com/q/660887/

Comment: @Did Sorry, I thought it's enough to include the answer from that question. The expectation part.

Comment: You have an unusual notion of attribution, to say the least.